# Validation for user input

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, validation

I want to compare two dates in jsp .validation should be like user should be alerted  when he enters a futre date ..Start Date or end date should not be future date..Date format  is 12-5-2011 10:51:49..Please help

Comment: you got the answer, please make respons of it. you can make accept, upvote or just comment on their answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's client side (js) validation you want, and the date string format is as you describe, you can convert that string to a Date and compare that to the current date/time:

```
var dat      = '12-5-2011 10:51:49',
    datarr   =  dat.split(/\-|\s/),
    chckDate = new Date([datarr[2],datarr[1],datarr[0]].join('/')+' '+datarr[3]);
alert (chkDate < new Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Date should handle that format fine.

```
if(Date('12-5-2010 10:51:49') > Date()) {
    // Future  
} else {
    // Past or present   
}
```

Comment: Not so. That would give you the current date or invalid date if you use `new Date...`. Date format should be yyyy=mm=dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: I tested in Chrome and it parsed the example date fine. May be I should have tested in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear where you want to do the validation. If you want to do it in JavaScript on the browser, I'd just pick one of the 1000's of JavaScript datepickers that are around. Most of them have an option to limit date input.

For instance this [jQuery DatePicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-maxDate)

If you want to do it in Java code (JSP), check the [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)